# Why does curl_global_init with the CURL_GLOBAL_SSL option takes too much time

Tags: performance, openssl, libcurl

I'm using curl-7.54.1 and openssl-1.0.2l on windows machine. I have find that when init libcurl with CURL_GLOBAL_SSL option takes more than 3 seconds while use the CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32 option takes a few milliseconds. Is that normal?

```
timer.tic();
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_SSL);
timer.toc();
```

Elapsed time is 3.603000 seconds.

```
timer.tic();
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32);
timer.toc()
```

Elapsed time is 0.002000 seconds.

Comment: It doesn't feel normal, no.